# Implementing >>= in newtype

Tags: haskell, instance, monads, typeclass

Let me start from the task I want solve, probably I'm going wrong way. I use Snap framework for toy project, and the main is that it's functions under `Snap` monad. I need to add my state above it. I use monad transformer:

```
type SnapApp a = StateT AppState Snap a
```

This defined in the module, say, `Base`. Since I need it in other modules, I have to export it:

```
module Base
  ( ..
  , SnapApp
  ) where
```

This is good, but I want that module doesn't exported that `SnapApp` is state monad, because I have some complicated processing for setting some attributes for the state. For example, session. I have to write file when it is changed, so it wrong to just `get` and than `put` modified session, special function should be called. So, I hide that using `newtype` and not data exporting construstor:

```
newtype SnapApp a = SnapApp (StateT AppState Snap a)
```

I made it instance of my class with functions for modifying session and etc. But problem arises: I lost instances of `Monad` class and other for new `SnapApp`. And I'm stuck with implementing `>>=`:

```
instance Monad SnapApp where
    return = SnapApp . return
    mx >>= fm = -- HOW?
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let the types guide you.
You need

```
(>>=) :: SnapApp a -> (a -> SnapApp b) -> SnapApp b
```

You have

```
(>>=) :: StateT AppState Snap a -> (a -> StateT AppState Snap b) -> StateT AppState Snap b
```

You need to convert:

- argument `SnapApp a` to `StateT AppState Snap a`
- argument `a -> SnapApp b` to `a -> StateT AppState Snap b`
- result `StateT AppState Snap b` to `SnapApp b`

1) use pattern matching; define:

```
fromSnapApp (SnapApp x) = x
```

2) Compose the functions `a -> SnapApp b` and `SnapApp b -> StateT AppState b`

3) Use `SnapApp`

Final result:

```
x >>= f = SnapApp (fromSnapApp x >>= (fromSnapApp . f))
```

or:

```
SnapApp x >>= f = SnapApp (x >>= (fromSnapApp . f))
```

You don't have to write this; GHC can derive the instance if you enable the [`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/deriving.html#newtype-deriving) extension:

```
newtype SnapApp a = SnapApp (StateT AppState Snap a) deriving (Monad)
```

Answer (score 3):

This state management is exactly what we designed snaplets to handle for you.  Our Handler monad is really just a newtype wrapper around `StateT s Snap` with a few extra things built in for convenience.  We do expose a MonadState instance which is what you're trying to avoid, but you could handle this by encapsulating your state type in a module and not exporting any accessors for it.  You could export only the desired Handler functions that do all your complicated attribute processing.

Comment: Oh, since I'm a Haskell beginner I will compare my code with Handler. Thank you!

Comment: There's a good bit of more complicated stuff in there that adds convenience to the exposed API, but will look complicated to beginners.  I'd suggest starting with the tutorials and API documentation instead.  You can also stop by #snapframework and get questions answered interactively and in depth.